# Is there a "global" definition of differential $1$-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ denote a smooth manifold. Then a *covector* at $p \in M$ is an element of the dual space of $T_p M$. We can organize covectors into a bundle over $M$, and then define a $1$-form on $M$ to be a section of this bundle.

> **Question.** Is there a more direct approach to defining $1$-forms, like so:
>
> A $1$-form on $M$ is a linear way of turning sections of $TM \rightarrow M$ into smooth functions $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying some smoothness or "locality" conditions.
>
> (I'm also interested in defining arbitrary $k$-forms in this way.)

Comment: I don't understand, you gave the exact answer to your question in your definition : a section of $T^*M$ is exactly the data of a function $f \in \mathfrak X(M)^*$. If you want this to be smooth, well take local trivialization and ask it to be smooth. What more do you want ?

Comment: Maybe you are annoyed with checking that all of these different constructions form bundles? If so, you can construct all them from the associated principle $GL_n(V)$ bundle $P$, and the appropriate $GL(V)$ representation $W$, as a balanced product $P \times_G W$. $W = V^*$ would give you the cotangent bundle, $\wedge^k (V^*)$ the bundle of $k$ forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
$\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}}$
Let $\O_M=C^\infty(M)$ be the ring of smooth functions on $M$.
Let $\D_M$ be the set of $\Bbb R$-linear derivations of the ring
$\O_M$. We can identify the elements of $\D_M$ with the smooth tangent
fields on $M$. Then $\D_M$ is an $\O_M$-module, and we can identify
the smooth $1$-forms with the module $\text{Hom}_{\O_M}(\D_M,\O_M)$.

This point of view is developed systematically in the book
*Smooth Manifolds and Observables* by "Jet Nestruev" (Springer GTM 220).

Answer (score 2):

You essentially said the same thing twice.  A covector *is* a way of turning a vector into a scalar.  Therefore a covector field (i.e., a differential 1-form on $M$) is a way of turning a vector field into a scalar field, i.e., a function on $M$.

Comment: But surely it's not an *arbitrary* (linear) way of turning vector fields into scalar fields?

Comment: Requiring smoothness is a separate issue! You wanted a global definition but the definition you gave is already a global definition.  Perhaps you can clarify your question. Are you looking for a global way of defining smoothness of functions or something? @goblin

Answer (score 0):

As Mikhail Katz says, a $1$-form $\alpha$ is a machine that eats vector fields and spits out functions. Nothing more than that. As many others before me commented, you already wrote this in your post. If *smoothness* is the issue that bothers you, just add the requirement $$X\;\mathrm{is\;smooth}\Rightarrow\alpha(X)\mathrm{\;is\;smooth.}$$